# Ice Melting Faster in Running Water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, phase-transition, ice

Is it me or have anybody else noticed that ice melts way faster in running water than if you keep it in water or just keep it on any rigid surface.The difference is enormous .Why is it so?

Comment: Maybe due to pressure created by running water helps in breaking it's structure

Comment: It’s because otherwise a layer of cold water builds up next to the ice. It’s like the reverse of why a breeze cools you down.

Comment: Compared to what? Non-running water of same temperature?

Comment: @Qmechanic Compared to non-running water **initially** at the same temperature, but which cools down when the ice melts, contrary to the running water, as per the answers below

Answer (score 2):

Each of the three scenarios involve a different rate of heat transfer to the ice. Without getting into all the equations, the following is qualitative explanation.

The slowest heat transfer rate occurs from still air to the ice. Air is a poor thermal conductor, so heat transfer from the air to the ice by conduction would be very slow. There is heat transfer by convection from the air to the ice, but it would be due to natural convection, which can be very slow compared to forced convection (blowing air over the ice).

When you place the ice on a solid surface presumably initially at room temperature, heat transfer occurs from the surface to the portion of the ice in contact with the surface by conduction. The rate of heat transfer can vary widely depending on the thermal conductivity of the surface material and its mass. It will be relatively slow if, for example, placed on a wood or plastic surface, compared to a stone surface like granite, or a metal pan. Heat transfer from the metal pan probably being the highest. For any surface, however, the heat transfer rate will be much greater than that for air.  As before, the heat transfer rate will be slowest for those portions of the ice in contact with air.

Placing the ice in a bowl of water will result in the ice melting rather quickly depending, of course, on how much water and what its original temperature is. Heat transfer from the water to the ice is both by conduction and natural convection (since the water is still).  However, as the ice melts the temperature of the surrounding water decreases, thus slowing down the heat transfer rate.

Running water is the same as still water except for the very important fact that the water contacting the ice is continually replaced by fresh water of the same temperature, so the heat transfer rate does not slow down due to lowering of the temperature of the water in contact with the ice. Compared to still water we now have heat transfer by conduction plus the most important heat transfer by forced convection.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: "However, as the ice melts the temperature of the surrounding water increases" - decreases?

Comment: @Adam Oops, decreases obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Heat moves between two media (in your example, the water and the ice) via three main mechanisms: radiation, conduction, and convection. Let's consider each in turn...

Radiation is the transfer of heat via electromagnetic waves. It doesn't require the materials to be in contact -- a perfect example is how the sun feels warm, even though it doesn't touch us or the atmosphere physically. Radiation scales with temperature to the fourth power, $T^4$. For your example of water melting ice, radiation is not a significant driver of the melting and can be safely ignored.

Conduction is the transfer of heat from one material to another by direct contact. The transfer of heat requires molecules from one material to collide with the molecules from the other. Temperature is a measure of how fast the molecules are bouncing around -- hotter things have molecules that bounce faster, while colder ones have molecules that bounce slower. When a hot (i.e. fast) molecule collides with a cold (i.e. slow) molecule, the energy is redistributed between them and the hot one moves a little slower (it gets colder) and the cold one moves a little faster (it gets hotter). The rate of conduction depends on the density of the materials and the temperature difference between them, because it relies on the collision of molecules.

Convection is related to conduction. Convection is the bulk movement of molecules. If there is bulk movement of molecules, that means fresh molecules can come in and collide and it also means the molecules from one medium is moving directly towards the other. Convection is the reason why a strong wind feels cold on your skin -- bulk motion of molecules of air collide with your body and take away heat. The bulk motion (wind) forces more particles to collide with your body that would happen by random chance if there was no wind, so more heat is removed from your body.

---

So what does that mean here?

When you put your ice on a flat surface in the air, it melts pretty slowly. Neglecting radiation, there is only conduction with the surface it is sitting on, and conduction into the air. Air is not very dense.

Contrast this with ice placed in a pool of water. It will melt faster than on air. Again, no radiation, but now the conduction is between the ice and liquid water. Liquid water is 1000 times more dense than air, and so it conducts heat much better. Way more collisions of water molecules with ice molecules to remove the heat.

Now make the water move around. We've just added convection to the mix. Now, when a water molecule gives some heat to the ice and gets a little cooler, it is quickly mixed away and a new, fresh, warm water molecule replaces it. This rapid, bulk turnover of water molecules makes the heat transfer to the ice faster. This results in very fast melting rates -- the power of convection combines with conduction!

---

This leads to the classic paradox. If you want to melt ice the fastest, do you use hot running water or cold running water?

I'll leave it to the readers to think about it. But it boils (get it?) down to whether the density matters more or the $\Delta T$ in convection and conduction.

Comment: Is hot running water vs cold running water a _paradox_?  Are there many situations where cold running water would actually warm better than warm running water?

Comment: @JMac Ice in water at a rolling boil melts slower than ice in a bath of cold running water. Although hot moving water out of a faucet is probably faster than cold moving water, when convection dominates conduction by a lot. The density of cold water is higher than density of hot water, and so there is a tradeoff between $\Delta T$ and $\rho$. I don't remember what the tipping point is, but it depends on the relative amounts of conduction and convection.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that?  I'm just thinking of the numbers in my head and I really can't wrap around how that would make any sense at all.  I wouldn't expect the decreased density of the water to have a greater effect than the temperature difference, unless you were comparing water vapour to liquid water maybe.

Comment: @JMac I'd have to dig through my class notes... I recall it was something along the lines of assuming the Nusselt number takes the form of a power law with respect to Reynolds and Prandtl numbers: $Nu \approx C Re^\alpha Pr^{1/3}$. Then finding where that number is maximized as a function of temperature using order of magnitude estimates for change in viscosity, density, heat capacity, and thermal conductivity with temperature. I think the kinematic viscosity changes by by an order of magnitude, while thermal conductivity changes by a handful of percent and heat capacity is roughly constant.

Comment: And the change with viscosity is negative, while change with thermal conductivity is positive. There was something to the problem about then picking different Reynolds numbers and seeing how the temperature that maximizes Nusselt number changes with Reynolds number, and how the total heat flux changes as both (based on $Nu (T_{max} - T_{freezing})$). It was a decade ago, so I'm going to vague memories...

Answer (score 1):

The amount of heat lost by the ice is proportional to the difference in temperature between the ice and its immediate surroundings.  When sitting in still water, the water near the ice cools down so the heat transfer slows down.  With running water the water is always warmer than the ice so the heat transfer does not slow down. See Newton's Law of Cooling.